# Advice regarding SUID and sudo on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Just wanting a bit of advice. I have root access to a server and I want to create a second user and execute everything via sudo should I need to rather than logging in as root. The file /etc/sudoers reads as:

```
Defaults        env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I have added a second user "bob" to the system and added them to the group sudo which should ensure that they can execute root commands. When attempting any sort of privileged action, I get the following error:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

My understanding is that I would have to set the SUID with

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo (or should this be g+s?)
```

which will enable me to execute sudo.

Are there are any security considerations I have to consider with this approach and is this correct? A lot of posts regarding this say that this is an error but the set up is a virtual server and I was only provided with root access. I believe `/usr/bin/sudo` has deliberately not been set SUID to restrict other users from running it and to ensure that I have to explicitly set it.

Comment: Something seems off with your system. Can you show the exact permissions on the `sudo` binary, and the exact command you are trying to run?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127668 2012-05-16 06:25 sudo`

This is as expected. I just think it's a security precaution set by my VH provider in the way I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have to `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo`.

What I found kinda weird is that all my installation of Ubuntu server (from 10.04LTS to 12.04LTS) always came with this +s set.
So, yes it is correct. Furthermore, performing actions through sudo rather than using root is a good approach regarding security. The log `/var/log/auth.log` logs what has been done through sudo calls.

Comment: Just did this and all seems fine. Thank you! My next thought is to remove login access for root which I guess I can do by changing the shell for the user with `chsh /usr/sbin/nologin root`. Also removing the line `root    ALL=(ALL) ALL` from /etc/sudoers will ensure that should root be able to login, they cannot run privileged commands. (Maybe that last part is superfluous to requirements!)

Comment: To remove root login, you'd better disable it from SSH, put in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:
`PermitRootLogin no`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Heis! I was wondering if it was an SSH restriction thing rather than amending user shells! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Just in case, you can also restrict root login just using SSH keys by putting: `PermitRootLogin without-password`

Comment: I think restricting it altogether is fine. It works much like my other set-up which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to execute the following commands:

```
chown root /usr/bin/sudo
chgrp root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Of course you have to run them as root!

Comment: Would I need to execute `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` if I have already run `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo`? Just clarifying. All permissions and groups are already set as you have advised.